# PostgreSQL Switchover and Switchback in 9.4.1

Tags: postgresql, replication, postgresql-9.4

Environment:

PostgreSQL EDB 9.4.1 
OS:rhel 7

I have configured streaming replication with continuous archiving.
I have performed the steps below for switch-over and switchback.

I have read [this](https://www.enterprisedb.com/blog/switchover-switchback-in-postgresql-9-3) other articles.

I am confused what happens if the archive location is not a shared location. 
I have followed the steps below for switchover and switchback.

### SWITCHOVER

#### At the master (192.xxxx.128)

- ```
  pg_ctl -D /opt/PostgresPlus/9.4AS/data stop --mode=fast
  ```
- Create `recovery.conf`:

  ```
  standby_mode = 'on'
  primary_conninfo = 'user=replication password=Replication@123 host=192.xxx.129 port=5432'
  recovery_target_timeline = 'latest'
  trigger_file = '/tmp/node1'
  restore_command = 'rsync -a /home/postgres/restore/%f %p
  ```
- ```
  pg_ctl -D /opt/PostgresPlus/9.4AS/data start
  ```
- ```
  psql -U postgres -c "select pg_is_in_recovery()"
  ```

#### At the standby (192.xx.129):

- ```
  ps -ef | grep postgres
  ```
- ```
  touch locationoftrigeerfile
  ```

#### AT the primary (192.xx.129):

- connect applications and test

Switch-over was completed with the above steps.

### NOW SWITCHBACK

#### AT the primary (192.xx.129):

- ```
  pg_ctl -D $PGDATA stop --mode=fast
  ```
- create `recovery.conf` and add

  ```
  standby_mode = 'on'
  primary_conninfo = 'user=replication password=postgres host=192.xxx.128 port=5432 sslmode=prefer sslcompression=1 krbsrvname=postgres'
  restore_command = 'cp %p /home/postgres/restore_5444/%f'
  recovery_target_timeline = 'latest'
  trigger_file='/tmp/pg_promote_5432'`
  ```
- ```
  pg_ctl -D $PGDATA start --mode=fast
  ```
- ```
  psql -U postgres -c "select pg_is_in_recovery();"
  ```

#### At the secondary (192.xxx.128):

- ```
  ps -ef | grep postgres
  ```
- ```
  touch locationoftrigeerfile
  ```

**My question:**

For every promotion a new timeline id is created as per the [PostgreSQL documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/recovery-target-settings.html).

If we use `recovery_target_timeline='latest'` then it will use the timeline which was found in the archive, but in my environment archive is not a shared mount point.

If the timeline is not found in the archive, is it received via streaming replication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the history file containing the timeline switch will also be streamed to the standby server.

It will show up in the standby's `pg_wal` directory. The associated log message is:

```
LOG:  fetching timeline history file for timeline 2 from primary server
```

The standby will be able to follow the primary across the timeline switch.

Comment: sorry for question again  I have tested same scenario this time I didn't mention recovery _target_timeline='latest' but when prod put into recovery and after I prompted slave to primary then DR is not starting replication it show replication terminated by primary server even I have send 000002.history file to restore location to dr still not working... please help me ...if you want I can post new question

Comment: I have posted new question about this please check. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59124137/is-it-mandatory-parameter-recover-target-timeline-latest-in-switchover-and-swi