# Is it mandatory parameter recover_target_timeline='latest' in switchover and switchback in PostgreSQL 9.4.1?

Tags: postgresql, replication, postgresql-9.4

I have followed below steps for switchover and switchback.

Step 1:-
Disconnect application services from 10.x.x.10 and do the following

**@Master(10.x.x.10)**

`pg_ctl -D /DATA_VEC/pgdata stop --mode=fast`

**@DR(20.x.x.20)**

promote DR as read write mode

Step 2:- Start master as DR from new primary

**@Master(10.x.x.10)**
create `recovery.conf`

```
standby_mode = 'on'
primary_conninfo = 'user= password= host=20.x.x.20 port=9999
trigger_file = '/tmp/node1'
restore_command = 'cp /DATA_VEC/restore/%f "%p"'
```

```
pg_ctl -D /DATA_VEC/pgdata start
```

after promotion new standby, old primary not getting syncing with new primary server(old standby)
Logs from DR server which was primary.

```
2019-12-01 18:46:56 IST LOG:  database system was shut down in recovery at 2019-12-01 18:46:53 IST
2019-12-01 18:46:56 IST LOG:  entering standby mode
cp: cannot stat `/DATA_VEC/restore/00000002.history': No such file or directory
2019-12-01 18:46:56 IST LOG:
2019-12-01 18:46:56 IST LOG:  restored log file "00000002000000000000000C" from archive
2019-12-01 18:46:57 IST LOG:  consistent recovery state reached at 0/C000090
2019-12-01 18:46:57 IST LOG:  record with zero length at 0/C000090
2019-12-01 18:46:57 IST LOG:  database system is ready to accept read only connections
2019-12-01 18:46:57 IST LOG:  started streaming WAL from primary at 0/C000000 on timeline 2
2019-12-01 18:46:57 IST LOG:  replication terminated by primary server
2019-12-01 18:46:57 IST DETAIL:  End of WAL reached on timeline 2 at 0/C000090.
2019-12-01 18:46:57 IST LOG:  restored log file "00000002000000000000000C" from archive
2019-12-01 18:46:57 IST LOG:  record with zero length at 0/C000090
2019-12-01 18:46:57 IST LOG:  restarted WAL streaming at 0/C000000 on timeline 2
2019-12-01 18:46:57 IST LOG:  replication terminated by primary server
2019-12-01 18:46:57 IST DETAIL:  End of WAL reached on timeline 2 at 0/C000090.
```

**@Master(10.x.x.10)**

Pg_xlog content

```
-bash-4.1$ cd pg_xlog
-bash-4.1$ ll
total 65552
-rw------- 1 postgres postgres      302 Dec  1 12:52 00000002000000000000000A.00000028.backup
-rw------- 1 postgres postgres 16777216 Dec  1 13:52 00000002000000000000000B
-rw------- 1 postgres postgres 16777216 Dec  1 14:28 00000002000000000000000C
-rw------- 1 postgres postgres 16777216 Dec  1 12:52 00000002000000000000000D
-rw------- 1 postgres postgres 16777216 Dec  1 12:52 00000002000000000000000E
-rw------- 1 postgres postgres       41 Dec  1 13:57 00000002.history
-rw------- 1 postgres postgres       83 Dec  1 13:57 00000003.history
drwx------ 2 postgres postgres     4096 Dec  1 13:57 archive_status
```

@in restore_command location content:-

`-bash-4.1$ cd /DATA_VEC/restore/
-bash-4.1$ ll
total 49156
-rw------- 1 postgres postgres 16777216 Dec  1 18:45 00000002000000000000000A
-rw------- 1 postgres postgres 16777216 Nov 30 21:22 00000002000000000000000B
-rw------- 1 postgres postgres 16777216 Dec  1 18:45 00000002000000000000000C
-rw------- 1 postgres postgres       83 Dec  1 18:45 00000003.history
-bash-4.1$`

as per_pg_xlog timeline history file `00000003.history`arrived at standby still not starting streaming from new primary.

**Question:-** 
1. Is it mandatory parameter `recover_target_timeline='latest'` in `recovery.conf` file" to get latest timeline id from new primary through streaming to start streaming replication?

2.If yes, is it for all PostgreSQL Version? like from 9.3 to 11.5

Answer (score 1):

If you want switch-back functionality, you will have to set `recovery_target_timeline='latest'`, as any promotion will increment the timeline.  Using a fixed target timeline is usually reserved for very specific cases (i.e., you need to recover changes after a split-brain, diverged-timeline scenario).

To answer your specific questions:

1. Yes
2. Yes