# PostgreSQL 9.4.1 Switchover & Switchback without recover_target_timeline=latest

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I have tested different scenarios to do switchover and switchback in postgreSQL 9.4.1 Version.

**Scenario 1:-** [PostgreSQL Switchover and Switchback in 9.4.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58949441/postgresql-switchover-and-switchback-in-9-4-1/58950362#58950362][1])

**Scenario 2:-** [Is it mandatory parameter recover_target_timeline='latest' in switchover and switchback in PostgreSQL 9.4.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59124137/is-it-mandatory-parameter-recover-target-timeline-latest-in-switchover-and-swi])

**Scenario 3:-** On this page

To test scenario 3 I have followed below steps to perform.

1) Stop the application connected to primary server.

2) Confirm all application was stopped and all thread was disconnected from primary DB.

@192.x.x.129(Primary)

3) Clean shutdown primary using

`pg_ctl -D$PGDATA  stop --mf`

@DR(192.x.x.128) side check sync status:

`postgres=# select pg_last_xlog_receive_location(),pg_last_xlog_replay_location();
-[ RECORD 1 ]-----------------+-----------
pg_last_xlog_receive_location | 4/57000090
pg_last_xlog_replay_location  | 4/57000090`

4)Stop DR server.DR(192.x.x.128)

`pg_ctl -D $PGDATA stop -mf`

pg_log:

`2019-12-02 13:16:09 IST LOG:  received fast shutdown request
2019-12-02 13:16:09 IST LOG:  aborting any active transactions
2019-12-02 13:16:09 IST LOG:  shutting down
2019-12-02 13:16:09 IST LOG:  database system is shut down`

@192.x.x.128(DR)

5) Make following changes on DR server.

`mv recovery.conf recovery.conf_bkp`

6)make changes in 192.x.x.129(Primary):

`[postgres@localhost data]$ cat recovery.conf
standby_mode = 'on'
primary_conninfo = 'user=replication password=postgres host=192.x.x.128 port=5432 sslmode=prefer sslcompression=1 krbsrvname=postgres'
restore_command = 'cp %p /home/postgres/restore/%f'
trigger_file='/tmp/promote'`

7)Start DR as read write mode:

`pg_ctl -D $DATA start`

pg_log:

`2019-12-02 13:20:21 IST LOG:  database system was shut down in recovery at 2019-12-02 13:16:09 IST
2019-12-02 13:20:22 IST LOG:  database system was not properly shut down; automatic recovery in progress
2019-12-02 13:20:22 IST LOG:  consistent recovery state reached at 4/57000090
2019-12-02 13:20:22 IST LOG:  invalid record length at 4/57000090
2019-12-02 13:20:22 IST LOG:  redo is not required
2019-12-02 13:20:22 IST LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
2019-12-02 13:20:22 IST LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
(END)`

We can see in above log OLD primary is now DR of Primary(Which was OLD DR) and not showing any error because timeline id same on new primary which is already exit in new DR.

8)Start Primary as read only mode:-

`pg_ctl -D$PGDATA start`

logs:

`2019-12-02 13:24:50 IST LOG:  database system was shut down at 2019-12-02 11:14:50 IST
2019-12-02 13:24:51 IST LOG:  entering standby mode
cp: cannot stat ‘pg_xlog/RECOVERYHISTORY’: No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat ‘pg_xlog/RECOVERYXLOG’: No such file or directory
2019-12-02 13:24:51 IST LOG:  consistent recovery state reached at 4/57000090
2019-12-02 13:24:51 IST LOG:  record with zero length at 4/57000090
2019-12-02 13:24:51 IST LOG:  database system is ready to accept read only connections
2019-12-02 13:24:51 IST LOG:  started streaming WAL from primary at 4/57000000 on timeline 9
2019-12-02 13:24:51 IST LOG:  redo starts at 4/57000090
(END)`

**Question 1:-** In This scenario i have perform only switch-over to show you. using this method we can do switch-over and switchback. but using below method Switch-over-switchback is work, then why PostgreSQL Community invented recovery_target_timeline=latest and apply patches see blog: https://www.enterprisedb.com/blog/switchover-switchback-in-postgresql-9-3 from PostgrSQL 9.3...to latest version.

**Question 2:-** What mean to say in above log `cp: cannot stat ‘pg_xlog/RECOVERYHISTORY’: No such file or directory` ?

**Question 3:-** I want to make sure from scenarios 1 and scenario 3  which method/Scenarios is correct way to do switchover and switchback? because scenario 2 is getting error because we must use `recover_target_timeline=latest` which all community experts know.

Comment: Using 9.4.1 is dangerously negligent. You have to use 9.4.25 at least, and given that this version will run out of service soon, you should upgrade.

Comment: Yes, I have upgrdaded in UAT.  I will upgrade to 11.5 in month of Jan-2020.

Answer (score 0):

Answers:

1. If you shut down the standby cleanly, then remove `recovery.conf` and restart it, it will come up, but has to perform crash recovery (`database system was not properly shut down`).

   The proper way to promote a standby to a primary is by using the trigger file or running `pg_ctl promote` (or, from v12 on, by running the SQL function `pg_promote`). Then you have no down time and don't need to perform crash recovery.

   Promoting the standby will make it pick a new time line, so you need `recovery_target_timeline = 'latest'` if you want the new standby to follow that time line switch.
2. That is caused by your `restore_command`.
3. The method shown in 1. above is the correct one.

Comment: Can you clarify Answer no 1.? Suppose weather i remove or mv to another,  standby will start to follow the timeline.  We can say without recovery_target_timeline we can do switchover and switchback. because we are not loosing any checkpoint in this (scenarios 3)  also. i want to know what is wrong in this.? my friend was telling he has done switch-over and switchback (DB size 500GB) using scenario 3.

Comment: Using scenario 3 i can preserve archive log sequence to restore archives from more than months. (here timeline id is not changing)

Comment: I don't understand your first comment. Yes, it is possible to fail over the way you propose, but it will be more work for the database and take longer. There is also no benefit to your method. You can restore backups and recover through time line switches.